# EF creates excess datatable

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

For example: context contains only two sets

```
 public class ConfigurationContext : DbContext
 {
    public ConfigurationContext() : base("ConfigurationContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ConfigurationContext, Proj.Configuration.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

     public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }    
}
```

In spite of this, the created database contains three tables:

[Screenshot of the created database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9sPD.png)

Every created database always contains such table 'Users'.
Why? The entity named 'User' has never existed in my project!

Comment: What do your classes look like? Which Migration steps are defined?

Comment: Problem exists even if the classes do not contain any properties except the primary key. Mirgation only defines AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; and AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

Comment: Please show us your `Tag` and `Source` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using any particular authentication while creating your new project. Sometimes Visual Studio will choose an authentication by default. In those cases Entity Framework will have to model the user.

Comment: I'll check, but the "age" column is unlikely to be associated with authentication

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in 'sys.model' database, where I have found one unintentionally created table named 'Users'.
When the database is created, all the tables from 'sys.model' database are copied to it. I have deleted this table and the problem has disappeared.